# Inserting text from database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, database

I've done a bit of searching for this but i seem to be struggling for answers, as the answers always seem to revolve around ASP:GRIDVIEW.

I've created a SqlDataSource which will pull the information from my database that i require. However all i want to do now is display those certain fields into areas that have been formatted already. I believe this is achieved by entering something like this <% %>.

This is my SqlDataSource:

```
asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ReviewConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ReviewConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [reviews] WHERE ([review] = ?)">
                              <SelectParameters>
                                  <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="={0}" Name="review" Type="String" />
                              </SelectParameters>
                              </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is where i want to display the data from my database

```
<h3>(I WANT A FIELD FROM MY DATABASE TO DISPLAY HERE!)</h3>
```

As i mentioned before i believe it includes the tags <% %>. But i may be well off.

Any help would be great!

Comment: use this link http://forums.asp.net/p/1583276/3995150.aspx#3995150

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at *asp:DetailsView* (instead of *asp:GridView*)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

DetailsView is displaying a single item just like GridView is displaying a list of items (in a table).

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="True" DataKeyNames="Key"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <h3><% Eval("Name") %></h3>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

However, I would've consider above a "hack" and instead I would do something different than binding myself to use a SqlDataSource.

If you have a regular web application, moving your sql statement to your "code behind" and binding the result to a literal would separate *View* better and make your UI code look simply like this:

```
<h3><asp:Literal ID="Header" runat="server" /></h3>
```

and then your code behind would bind the Literal simply like this:

```
Header.Text = "Hello World";
```

I didn't add the code for getting data from your SQL Database since I don't agree with the approach here as well. I would have made a LINQ Data Context (or used Entity Framework) to map my SQL schema to a C# entity model. If you did this, it would have been very straight forward to select element from code behind:

```
using(var db = new MyLinqDataContext())
{
    var review = db.Reviews.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Review = myReview);
    if(review != null)
        Header.Text = review.Name;
}
```